# Stream call twice, listView data become duplicate

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, stream-builder

I using [flutter_uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader) to upload file to server. I putting the listener in the main.dart. Once data uploaded successfully, the listView in pageA will refreshed.

**main.dart**

```
 StreamSubscription<UploadTaskResponse> _subscription;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     _subscription = uploader.result.listen(
        (result) {
           _bloc.getData(..); // refresh in page A
    });
  }
```

**pageA.dart**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc.getData(..); 
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
body:  StreamBuilder<List<ABC>>(
  stream: _bloc.abcStreem,
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // return listView code
    }
  )
    ...
 }
```

**bloc**

```
Future refreshListView(...) async {
    List<ABC> abc;
    try {
      abc = await _repo.getList(...);
      abcSink.add(abc);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Caught $e');
    }
  }
```

When I switch to others page while data uploading, then switch back to pageA, sometime it will show duplicate data if the data is uploaded successfully and pageA initState call at the same time.

Is there a way I can prevent it?

Comment: You are calling _bloc.refreshListView(..) twice.

Comment: @CeltK.B. ya, but how to prevent that? I need to have listener in main

Comment: Why do you call it again in page A? It doesn't work if you call it only in the main?

Comment: @CeltK.B. the listener used to check the result of the file uploader.  If data uploaded successfully it will refresh. I still need to place the same method in page A initState . Without that code in pageA, my listView is empty.

Comment: How about to make sure that abc and abcSink empty, set it to empty abc and empty abcSink before try and catch condition inside refreshListView?

Answer (score 0):

before adding data, empty the list where data adding.
It's working for me.

```
Future refreshListView(...) async {
List<ABC> abc;
try {
abc = [];
  abc = await _repo.getList(...);
  abcSink.add(abc);
} catch (e) {
  print('Caught $e');
}
 }
```

Comment: Since the list "abc" is created everytime the method refreshListView is called, initialising the list with an empty array won't change a thing. The problem here is with the Stream and not with the List itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you're adding your full list twice to your Stream with the method `abcSink.add(abc);`

This is a conception problem.

In this case, when the method `uploader.result.listen` completes, you should not retrieve the whole list again, but only the newly created item.
If you can isolate the new item added to the list, you simply have to add it to your stream

```
abcSink.add(myNewItemABC);
```

If it's not possible for you to retrieve a single item, and your only way is to retrieve the whole list, you're losing the benefits of the Stream.
You should consider using a FutureBuilder instead of the StreamBuilder

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: refreshListView(),
    initialData: [],
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return YOUR_LISTVIEW_CODE;

      }
    }
),
```

After updating the refreshListView() method so it can return `_repo.getList(...);` directly